# How to regain access to a SQL Server database created by another user in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I've just created a new Google Cloud Platform SQL Server managed instance. After logging in as the default user (sqlserver), I've created a new role with the following code:

```
CREATE SERVER ROLE MyDBCreatorRole AUTHORIZATION CustomerDbRootRole
Grant CONNECT SQL TO MyDBCreatorRole as CustomerDbRootRole
Grant Create any database TO MyDBCreatorRole as CustomerDbRootRole
```

Then I've created a new user (dbcreatoruser), logged in with the new user and created a new database (newdb1). The standard sqlserver user is not able to access to the new database since it has no rights on the db created by the new user.
Then I've deleted the dbcreatoruser user (it is a test environment).

Since the Google Cloud Platform does not give access to "sysadmin" functions, is there a way to regain control of the "newdb1" database?

All my attempts to create a server role with enough rights to modify the database has failed since the standard CustomerDbRootRole has not enough rights to do it. I'm working on a test environment, but I wonder what should I do if things go bad on production environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that you cannot use super privileges for Cloud SQL in general[1], I think the best approach would be to determine the user who created the database is the root user and never delete it.

Also I think you should contact Google Cloud support if things go bad in production either by creating a PIT[2] or creating a case[3] and see what they can do for you to drop that database.

If for future business requirements, you need to have Super privileges in SQL Server, you may also want to raise a feature request like [4]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq

[2] https://issuetracker.google.com/

[3] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases

[4] https://issuetracker.google.com/74357883

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll try to workaround the issue by providing a stored procedure accessible to a specific set of users that creates the database and automatically adds the sqlserver user as db_owner